# Uncaught TypeError: [] is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

i am using vue js 2.6.10 and just after i am updating all my package on npm then my apps is not working at all in production environment... it just working fine on development environment

the error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: [] is not a function
```

and when i check on source the error is come from this

```
), [], !1, null, null, null).exports
      , va = []((function() {
        if ("undefined" != typeof document) {
            var t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
              , e = document.createElement("style")
              , a = " a[data-v-11b2e33f] { cursor: pointer; } ";
            e.type = "text/css",
            e.styleSheet ? e.styleSheet.cssText = a : e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a)),
            t.appendChild(e)
        }
    }
```

which i have no idea what is it mean. i tried to do npm install, and npm update to make sure everything is updated accordingly but still no luck

here is my vue app package.json (maybe this could help)

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
        "sass": "^1.23.7",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^15.0.0",
        "echarts": "^4.5.0",
        "fibers": "^4.0.2",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "hooper": "^0.3.4",
        "katex": "^0.10.2",
        "laravel-vue-pagination": "^2.3.1",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
        "v-tooltip": "^2.0.2",
        "vee-validate": "^2.2.15",
        "vue-ckeditor5": "^0.4.1",
        "vue-cleave-component": "^2.1.3",
        "vue-context-menu": "^2.0.6",
        "vue-echarts": "^4.0.4",
        "vue-echarts-v3": "^2.0.1",
        "vue-json-excel": "^0.2.98",
        "vue-katex": "^0.3.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
        "vue-truncate-collapsed": "^2.1.0",
        "vue2-filters": "^0.8.0",
        "vuex": "^3.1.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: What package(s) did you update before this problem started?

Comment: almost all on devDependencies except vue and vue-template-compiler

Comment: Have you tried disabling minimizing in Webpack to see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: You should have a `webpack.config.js`. Either add this or set it to `false` if it already exists: `optimization: { minimize: false }`.

Comment: i just can't make this laravel-mix to not optimize/minimizing... tried a lot of way on the internet but none work

Answer (score 0):

```
), [], !1, null, null, null).exports
      , va = []((function() {
        if ("undefined" != typeof document) {
            var t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
              , e = document.createElement("style")
              , a = " a[data-v-11b2e33f] { cursor: pointer; } ";
            e.type = "text/css",
            e.styleSheet ? e.styleSheet.cssText = a : e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a)),
            t.appendChild(e)
        }
    }
```

I think line 2 is a problem. You shouldn't have any statement after `[]`, so you should add line break after `[]`

Something like this

```
va = [];((function() {
...
```

Comment: I don't think this is code OP has written. It's only in production and it appears to be minified code.

Comment: so how do i fix it? i mean this code is auto generated from running npm run prod.... and it is working fine is i am doing npm run watch or npm run dev

Comment: have you try adding `;` to the line corresponding to this problem in source code and rebuild it?

Comment: i have no idea where i shoud adding those mark in the source code... and i don't think this is related to my source code but more about my package or there is something not right with npm build?

Comment: You mean those lines are from external libs?

Comment: well to be honest i have no idea, i even tried to go back to my old version of this app from github before updating anything and it still getting this kind of error, i think there is something wrong with npm compiler or whatever